# C# - Creating an index including a column name which is a keyword

Tags: c#, ms-access, indexing

I have a C# program that creates Access MDB files.  The names of the tables and columns are fixed, and I have no chance to change them.  And unfortunately, one of the columns is named "Group".

The code that I have written looks like:

```
string indexSQL = buildIndexString(table.TableName);
//indexSQL = "CREATE INDEX comp ON ExpFactMap([Group]);"
new OleDbCommand(indexSQL, conn).ExecuteNonQuery();
```

When ExecuteNonQuery() is executed, I get a syntax error.  The code works correctly if I use any column other than "Group".  The problem seems to be that it is interpreting Group as a keyword rather than as a column name.

Does anyone know how to get around this problem?  In an ideal world, I would change the name of the column, but unfortunately that is not a possibility.

Comment: exactly why is that not possible?

Comment: What you have should work, are you sure indexSQL is exactly "CREATE INDEX comp ON ExpFactMap([Group]);" with both the curly and square brackets?

Comment: Try "CREATE INDEX comp ON ExpFactMap(([Group]));"

Comment: In you code snippet buildIndexString is returning the SQL string to be executed. Are you sure that string contains the column name in square brackets?

Comment: see SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2cf5d/1/0 this just works fine, it must be something else in your c# code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group is not the only reserved word you're attempting to use as an object name in your DDL statement:

```
//indexSQL = "CREATE INDEX comp ON ExpFactMap([Group]);"
```

Unfortunately, "comp" is also a reserved word.  See [Problem names and reserved words in Access](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html#C).

Bracket that reserved word in your `CREATE INDEX` statement:

```
CREATE INDEX [comp] ON ExpFactMap([Group]);
```

Comment: Yep, you are right, and I feel kind of dumb.  Somehow it didn't occur to me that comp was also a keyword.  The brackets around comp fixed the problem.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: In addition to that page I linked, Allen Browne also provides a free utility to check your Access database for problem object names (and other potential "gotcha" issues): http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueChecker.html